# React JS, library problem with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a beginner in react, I learned using a (french) tutorial for learning react native. I have a new library in my project and I added react-navigation, i don't know why i have this error when I check my device.

"Unable to resolve module 'react-navigation-stack' from 'Navigation/Navigation.js' (my files) react-navigation-stack could not be found within the project.

Here is the link to the french tutorial: https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4902061-developpez-une-application-mobile-react-native/5046301-concevez-une-navigation-entre-vos-vues

Thanks you so much if you can help me.  I don't understand why it does not work

Package.json :

```
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste your package.json?

Comment: I have edit my message, thanks if you can help me

Comment: Hi @bababibi, it looks like you did not install `react-navigation-stack`. You can install it by running `npm install react-navigation-stack` or if you are using yarn `yarn add react-navigation-stack`. Once you install it, you should see `react-navigation-stack` under `dependencies` in your `package.json` file. The error that you are seeing, "Unable to resolve module" is typically caused by not having a package installed.

Comment: I have already install it, so i think it's because the installation don't work, i will maybe restart all, and but my files in the new projet, ty for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your guide is using React Navigation 4, and it has a link to React Navigation page which has been updated to use version 5.

So you are probably missing some dependencies here, but since you are learning, it would be best to move to the new version and follow the [Getting started guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) to install new version and all dependencies, and then use:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

You also have a code example there: [Hello React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, i don't understand all, i have change my code for have this :
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from '@react-navigation/stack'
So now i have this error... It look like the same, so i don't have idea about what i can do
 Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/stack" from "Navigation\Navigation.js"

Comment: Please follow the linked guide to install React Navigation 5, and then look at the example application there before changing your code.

Comment: Thanks, i will continue to check that and continue to learn, i will tell you if that continue to don't works

Comment: I have install the new version, and changes the code, now it's this error with the nativ, import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

I willc continue to check that tomorow, thanks for the help